# Seminar concearning Spectral Theory of Differential Operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, spectral-theory

I must prepare a seminar about spectral theory of linear partial differential operators. However, I'm at a loss as to a nice reference. I'm looking for something that fits in a graduate spectral theory course.

My teacher was following the book **Introductory Functional Analysis (I. Kreyszig)** (which is not too advanced) so the exposition must be at the same level (but if needed I have the freedom to use Fourier analysis and Sobolev Spaces).

Furtheremore, I should deal with the spectrum of the Laplacian operator.

Books and class notes recommendations are both welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: How long is your seminar?

Comment: About four lectures of 90 minutes..